# For a given string which contains only digits , what's the optimal approach to return all valid ip address combinations?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Example:

Given “25525511135”

Output : [“255.255.11.135”, “255.255.111.35”]. (sorted order)

Kindly let me know if we could do a depth first search over here ?(that's the only thing striking me )

Comment: Is 25.52.55.11 also a valid IP under your conditions? (it is a valid IP in general)

Comment: Could you tell us the format for valid ip addresses so it's not something we have to look up.

Comment: @shapiroyaacov Correct bro but in this case the addresses have to be formed such that all the characters from the string are used , deleting or inserting new characters is not allowed

Comment: @user2802557 assume IPV4 over here and the format is that all characters from given string have to be used ....

Comment: people don't all know what IP4 is, add the definition to the question and you will get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it important to have an 'optimal' approach for answering this?

There are not many permutations so the simple approach of checking every combination that fits into the IP format and then filtering out those that have out of range numbers will easily work.

It's unlikely to be a bottle neck for whatever this is part of.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a dynamic programming algorithm for the general case (something like 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/).

Instead of testing whether prefixes can be segmented into words in the dictionary, you'd be testing to see whether the prefixes are prefixes of some valid IPv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

Brutal DFS is acceptable in this problem:

```
class Solution{
private:
    vector<string> ans;
    int len;
    string cur, rec, str;

    bool IsOk(string s) {
        if(s[0] == '0' && s.size() > 1) return false;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i ++) {
            if(s[i] == '.') return false;
            sum = sum * 10 + s[i] - '0';
        }
        if(sum >= 0 && sum <= 255) return true;
        return false;
    }

    void dfs(int x, int cnt) {
        if(x == len) {
            if(str.size() != len + 4) return ;
            string tmp(str);
            tmp.erase(tmp.size() - 1, 1);
            if(cnt == 4) ans.push_back(tmp);
            return ;
        }
        if(cnt > 4 || str.size() > len + 4) return ;
        string tmp = cur;
        cur += rec[x];
        if(!IsOk(cur)) {
            cur = tmp;
            return ;
        }
        dfs(x + 1, cnt);

        string tmp2 = cur + '.';
        str += tmp2;
        cur = "";
        dfs(x + 1, cnt + 1);
        str.erase(str.size() - tmp2.size(), tmp2.size());
        cur = tmp;
    }

public:
    vector<string> restoreIpAddresses(string s) {
        this->len = s.size();
        this->rec = s;
        cur = str = "";
        ans.clear();
        dfs(0, 0);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://github.com/aailyin/algorithms-sandbox/blob/master/ips-from-string.js) is a recursive solution on JavaScript. The result is not sorted.

```
// Task from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-generate-possible-valid-ip-addresses-given-string/
// Given a string containing only digits, restore it by returning all possible valid IP address combinations.
//
// Example:
// Input : 25525511135
// Output : [“255.255.11.135”, “255.255.111.35”]
//

(function () {
    function getValidIP(str) {
        const result = [];
        const length = str.length;

        check(0, 0, '');

        function check(start, level, previous){
            let i = 0;
            let num;

            if (level === 3) {
                num = str.substring(start);
                if (num && num < 256) {
                    result.push(`${previous}.${num}`);
                }
                return;                
            }
            num = str.substring(start, start + 1);
            if (num == 0) {
                check(start + 1, level + 1, level === 0 ? `${num}`: `${previous}.${num}`);
            } else {
                while (num.length < 4 && num < 256 && start + i + 1 < length) {
                    check(start + i + 1, level + 1, level === 0 ? `${num}`: `${previous}.${num}`);
                    i++;
                    num = str.substring(start, start + i + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    console.log('12345:')
    console.time('1-1');
    console.log(getValidIP('12345'));
    console.timeEnd('1-1');    

    console.log('1234:')
    console.time('1-2');    
    console.log(getValidIP('1234'));
    console.timeEnd('1-2');    

    console.log('2555011135:')
    console.time('1-3');
    console.log(getValidIP('2555011135'));
    console.timeEnd('1-3');    

    console.log('222011135:')
    console.time('1-4');
    console.log(getValidIP('222011135'));
    console.timeEnd('1-4');    
})();
```